# Jquery highlight current menu item error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error in firebug: "Jquery is not defined" after I try to run my script.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('/startuprcz/sample-page')){
            JQuery('.main-navigation a[href="http://zdenekbenes.eu/startuprcz/sample-page/"]').parent('li').addClass('currentMenu');
        }else{
            JQuery('.main-navigation a[href="http://zdenekbenes.eu/startuprcz/"]').parent('li').addClass('currentMenu');
    }
});
```

Comment: You likely need to replace ``JQuery`` with ``jQuery``. Variable names are Case-sensitive in EMCAScript

Comment: @Indy, make answer, since OP already included jQuery in header...

Comment: Thank you very much case sensitive error :D

Comment: @nevermind [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809123) is correct

Comment: @Indy, yes, but you was faster. However, nevermind... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery library , in order to work with jQuery. Also it's not `JQuery` , it's `jQuery`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('/startuprcz/sample-page')){
                jQuery('.main-navigation a[href="http://zdenekbenes.eu/startuprcz/sample-page/"]').parent('li').addClass('currentMenu');
            //--^----   
            }else{
                jQuery('.main-navigation a[href="http://zdenekbenes.eu/startuprcz/"]').parent('li').addClass('currentMenu');
            //--^----   
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I work on wordpress, can i use it in wordpress theme as u defined ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define jquery lib in header